# Docusign - return url wrong event

Tags: docusignapi

When the user redirected from docusign to my app, docusign append an event.

The event parameter will have one of the following values:

- cancel (recipient canceled the signing operation)
- decline (recipient declined to sign)
- dexception (an exception occurred)
- dfax_pending (recipient has a fax pending)
- dsession_timeout (session timed out)
- dsigning_complete (signer completed the signing ceremony)
- dttl_expired (the time to live timer expired)
- dviewing_complete (recipient completed viewing the envelope)

So few days before when user sign the contract it returned correct event=signing_complete, but today I noticed that in the same scenarion it returns me event=viewing_complete.

Is it bug or not, that instead of signing_complete I get viewing_complete as it was before? Because I have some check accordingly to this event

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Robert Is it bug or not, that instead of signing_complete I get viewing_complete as it was before?
Because I have some check accordingly to this event

Comment: We also started seeing this yesterday.  Seems to be limited to sandbox environment, at-least for us.

Comment: @343_Guilty_Spark, yeah also reproduced it on demo account
I'm not able to test it on live account. So I hope that it works there

Answer (score 1):

The correct behavior is event=signing_complete, as you stated above. There is a patch that will be a DocuSign needed to address this, I do not have an ETA.

Comment: Thanks, Luis...do you know if its limited to demo env or can/will it affect production?

Comment: It is indeed DEMO only at this point and they will be addressing it some time today.

Comment: thanks, they did confirm it was DEMO only as was resolved later that day